# Load single <td>Table data in different rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I am trying to call an api and load the data to the table, the data gets added in the same row. But each data should be added in a separate row. Btw, I have just one `<td>` How do i solve this problem?

HTML:

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="editable-datatable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="footable-sortable"> Host 
                <span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center" id="concat_here">

          <tr>
<td id="row1">
</td>
          </tr>
          </span>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

JS:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
{
    obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    list_length = obj.log_ast.length;

    var i=0;
    for(i=0; i<list_length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML+'<tr>'+'<td>'+obj.log_ast[i].address+'</td>'+'</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to insert `<tr>` into a `<tr>` which is invalid. New rows should go into the `<tbody>`

Comment: @charlietfl din work. Still got all the output in same row.

Comment: I replaced <tr> </tr>  with <tbody> </tbody> but it did not work

Comment: Also, this did not work. document.getElementById('concat_here').innerHTML = document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML+'<tr>'+'<td>'+obj.log_ast[i].address+'</td>'+'</tr>';
.. The output has 2 rows but this displayed one of it

Comment: What's the value of `obj`?

Comment: document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('concat_here').innerHTML+'<tbody>'+'<td>'+obj.log_ast[i].address+'</td>'+'</tbody>';
This gives all outputs one below the other but in a same row.

Comment: @user7290573 It's json array of objects

Comment: No....still invalid html. A `<tbody>` needs `<tr>` as children. Now you are trying to put `<tbody>` inside `<tbody>` and `<td>` inside the inner tbody

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please show it in form of code?

Comment: Just change the id so the `<tr>` you are currently creating go inside the existing `<tbody>`

Comment: Added the screenshot. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper way" is to make a table row using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

```
var table = document.getElementById("editable-datatable")
var row = table.insertRow()
```

then add a cell to the row using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell

```
var cell = row.insertCell()
```

then add your text to the cell using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

```
cell.innerText = obj.log_ast[i].address
```

Comment: Your code is adding rows and inserting the outputs in each row but that row isn't being counted as one among the table. This is what i get "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries"

Comment: and that one row is empty

Comment: @rojoka I tested it and it works. Maybe you're missing a } or have some other bug.

Comment: See, your code works perfectly to add the rows but the table isn't counting that row as it own, also first row is empty which shouldn't be there because new values are added

Comment: Just delete the blank row from your HTML?

Comment: <tr id="row1"> Its because of this. Cannot remove this because other functionalities are added to this id.

Comment: Also, this shouldn't be empty when we insert the values, right?

Comment: Just checked, if i remove that from html. It says mo data in the table, 0 entries

Comment: Added the screenshot. Please check

Comment: Maybe put the row1 row inside your thead?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for exactly this code snippet.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="editable-datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="footable-sortable"> Host 
  <span class="footable-sort-indicator"></span>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="text-center" id="concat_here">

</span>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
           {
             obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
             list_length = obj.log_ast.length;
             var i=0;
             for(i=0; i<list_length; i++)
             {
                var htmlContent = '<td>'+obj.log_ast[i].address+'</td>';
                var refTbl =  document.getElementById('editable-datatable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                var newRow   = refTbl.insertRow(refTbl.rows.length);
                newRow.innerHTML = htmlContent
             }
           }
```

Comment: Your code is adding rows and inserting the outputs in each row but that row isn't being counted as one among the table. This is what i get "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries"

Comment: and that one row is empty.

Comment: Are you not expecting the addition of rows in your table?

Comment: Do you want to count that row as well? I have removed that row from the html.

Comment: yes. It should be in the count.
Your code adds the rows but it comes below that one empty row and only that row is being counted

Comment: Also when rows are inserted that empty row shouldn't be there , right?

Comment: If you want to keep the existing row and populate value inside it then before starting loop you have to fill your existing row like this  document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML = '<td>'+obj.log_ast[i].address+'</td>';

Comment: And after this make sure to start your loop from 1.

Comment: Tried what you said, it adds a value to that row and then other rows are added. but the problem is that the table is just counting that 1 row of its own and not the others.

Comment: So what I understand that you want a table inside your tr tag. tr cannot contain multiple rows inside it.

Comment: Adding the screenshot. Please check.

Comment: But we can create multiple tr for a td, right?
How to do that here?

Comment: No you cannot directly add tr inside td. You can only add tr inside a table. If you want to add multiple tr inside td tag. First, create a table inside td and add then multiple tr.

Comment: Did you check the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I have seen the screenshot.

Comment: Would running this in for loop work? <tbody class="text-center" id="concat_here">

      <tr id="row1">

      </tr>
    
    </tbody>

Comment: Check out this fiddle. Let me know what are you trying. You cannot keep multiple tbody inside a table.

Comment: the code i posted on SO  had an error. row1 is td not tr. Updated the code in question

Comment: It is <tr> <td id="row1"> </td> </tr>

Comment: So you want to add multiple rows inside this td. If it is, then create a table inside your td tag and add multiple rows in it.